How can I delete multiple lists in different SPO sites?
I'm trying to find a way to delete multiple lists created on different SPO sites for a task.
I've got the list names and the sites in a csv file. Is there a way to import the csv file, action upon the sites and their lists one by one using PowerShell?
These are empty lists so the requirement to delete the items isn't there.

Please show us the code you have already tried yourself. Explain what happened and if you have error messages, show these in full as well. Also provide a sample of the csv file you mention. Do this by editing your post and add it as formatted text, not as a comment.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Figure out a way to delete just one name, site pair.  2.  Write a loop to step through the CSV file, calling a function that you will write with two parameters, name and site.  3.  Convert the code you wrote in step 1 into a function that you can call from the loop you wrote in step 2.  4.  Test and debug.


When I was learning powershell, I wrote a generic tool for this kind of situation.  I later learned that this kind of tool is called a template engine.  My tool is available on github, but it is overkill in your case, and you are better off learning enough powershell to code this problem without a template engine.

You can use PowerShell to do this.
You would need to use either of the following Modules:
SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline (Legacy, WindowsPowerShell, https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline)
PnP.PowerShell (Recommended, Powershell 7, https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/pnp.powershell)
The documentation on the latter is quite up to date:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html
For the code, I am assuming you have a CSV file with the following format:
SiteUrl,ListName
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1,Documents
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site2,TestList

To load the CSV file, loop through the rows, connect to the target sites and delete the target lists, you can use the following script, assuming you use the PnP.PowerShell module.
#Import the PnP.PowerShell module
Import-Module PnP.PowerShell

#Define the path to the CSV file
$CSVFilePath = "C:\PathToYoutFile\CSVFile.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $CSVFilePath

#Loop through the CSV rows
foreach ($entry in $csv) {
    $SiteUrl = $entry.SiteUrl
    $ListName = $entry.ListName
    Write-Output "Working on Site '$SiteUrl', List '$ListName'"
    try {
        #Connect to the target SiteCollection / Subweb
        $null = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Interactive
        Write-Output "Deleting List '$ListName'"
        #Delete the List
        $null = Remove-PnPList -Identity $ListName -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to Connect and/or delete List. Error:"
        Write-Output $_
    }
}

If you use the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline, replace the Import-Module line with
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

and the Connect-PnPOnline line with
$null = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -UseWebLogin

